# Resizing graphs represented as adjacency matrices

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, matrix

In case I decide to use the "adjacency matrix" representation to represent a graph, how would I know what the size of the matrix should be?

All of the code examples I have seen, assume that the size is given to the `Graph` object to initialize the matrix, but it is not clear to me where did this size came from.
I mean the I assume that to build, a graph the data of the graph are loaded e.g. from a file, and the best approach would be to create the graph as you read the file (right so far?).
This is very easy using the alternative representation which is lists.
But in the case of `matrix` we don't know the number of vertices until the file is actually loaded. I don't believe that we first read the file (which could contain millions of vertices) and *then* build the graph. It seems to me like double processing.

So what is the usual/best way?

**Note:** I am aware of benefits of using lists instead, but since most docs say that on dense graphs, using a matrix is acceptable (but not for sparse) I am trying to understand how a program using the `matrix` representation is implemented properly.

Comment: Well, it seems your problem is basically storing a possibly infinite array. Try Table Doubling.

Comment: It think you should use dynamic reallocation of the matrix. The implementation greatly depends on the problem itself. Simply, put dynamic reallocation means that you first reserve some space for the matrix (let's say for n0Xn0) and when you finished all the space available you reserves a larger space, copy the contents and free the space. Details for the implementation depends on the language you use (C,C++ or Java) and also on the input (depending how the nodes are named, you might need a hash function from the name to the actual row or column). Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know the format of the input data? Delimited/fixed length?

Comment: @user845279:The format of the data? Lines of: VertexX VertexY Cost

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a count of vertices to begin with I believe you can only init the matrix with a boilerplate number. Let's say the input file only contains lines of the form `x y z` which means there's an edge from `x` to `y` with an (optional) cost `z`. Notice that the number of lines in the input file is the edge count of the graph, assuming the file contains nothing else. Since you already assume it is a dense graph, also assume that it is a complete graph which has number of edges equal to `n(n-1)/2` where `n` is the number of vertices. With this information you can come up with a close enough approximation of the number of vertices. For example, if the edge count from the input file is `1000000` then solving the equation 
`n*(n-1)/2 = 1000000` we arrive at `n` approximately equal to `1415`. Initializing the matrix to `1415*1415` array should cover you nicely.

Of course all of this is based on the fact that you have a fast enough way to read the number of lines in the input file.

Comment: I don't follow:If know the number of lines in the file doesn't it mean that I have read-in all the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the size well if the input format is under your control. In the example below, all of the values have a fixed length (6 chars) with 0 padding to the left. This means that each line will be 22 bytes in size. When you divide the size of the file by 22, you get the approximation of the matrix size.  If the graph is complete, the file size is equal to `nxn`, where n is the number of vertices.

Example:

```
000001 000020 000030
000800 000001 000040
      etc...
```

The other solution is to double the size of the matrix each time the size is exceeded. The amortized computational cost will be small. On the other hand, memory could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

the usual/best way is given in the comments: you reallocate and copy.  if you scale the size each time (eg double) the amortized (average) cost comes out as O(n), as far as i remember.  this is how, for example, python has lists that grow to be any size you need.  it's completely standard/common.

[i'm not really posting for points here; just frustrated that the answers in comments are what you need, but that you may not be paying attention to them or understanding them]